# Data missing in extra_fields in /collectors/{id}/recipients

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to get the response with this query from SurveyMoneky:

```
/collectors/{id}/recipients?include=survey_response_status,mail_status,custom_fields,remove_link,extra_fields,survey_link
```

Response I am getting is:

```
"last_name": "Siraj",
"first_name": "Abdullah",
"survey_response_status": "completely_responded",
"mail_status": "sent",
"email": "***",
"href": "****",
"custom_fields": {
    "1": null,
    "6": "2017"
},
"remove_link": "****",
"id": "3310118350",
"survey_link": "****"
```

My problem is:

1. I am supposed to get the extra_fields which I am not receiving
2. custom_field 1 is definitely not null, its wrong data.

The actual values of those fields are:

```
"extra_fields": {
    "job_item_id": "123456",
    "year": "2017"
},

"custom_fields": {
    "1": "123456",
    "6": "2017"
}
```

I checked with this call: `/collectors/{id}/recipients/{id}` and this works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This seems more like a bug than an issue with what you're doing. I'd suggest contacting SurveyMonkey API support and they can dig into the specific collector/contacts and see what's going on.

Comment: Seems you are right. I reported this to surveymonkey